# How do I graph the following curve without using a calculator $y^2=x\sin x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions, curves

I have to graph the following curve by hand without taking the derivative of it.
If you could help in any way that would be lovely.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Graph $y^2 = x$ (a pair of uni-directional square root curves heading off in the 1st and 4th quadrants; the 4th quadrant curve will be the reflection about the $x$-axis of the 1st quadrant curve), then draw a "sine-like curve" between the positive $x$-axis and the 1st quadrant square root curve you drew, then include the reflection about the $x$-axis of this "sine-like curve". Probably need to consider some geometric calculus ideas to get curvatures roughly correct, especially at the $x$-axis intercepts.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first understand $y=x\sin x$. It's bound between the lines $y=\pm x$, which form two "cones" touching at the origin. The curve touches each line infinitely often, where $\pi/2|x$. So it looks a bit like $\sin x$, but with larger oscillations as we move away from $x=0$ in either direction. It's an even function rather than an odd one, but the roots - multiples of $\pi$ are the same. You should be able to sketch it.

Now, what about $y^2=x\sin x$? This time, there are three key changes. Firstly, the bounds are now $\pm\sqrt{x}$ instead, so the oscillations don't grow as much. Secondly, the regions where $x\sin x<0$ are deleted, so there are infinitely many width-$\pi$ gaps. Finally, $y=\pm\sqrt{x\sin x}$, so if you work out what happens with $y\ge0$, it's mirrored below the $x$-axis.